# Apache catch all domains and redirect and get domain as param

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am giving an experimental go at "multisite-cms". My problem is catching up all domains and redirecting with params, for instance:

www.domain.com will be redirected at www.maindomain.com/index.php?d=www.domain.com

but while the maindomain.com not showing, so it looks like its www.domain.com at all times.

Thanks.

Comment: There are too many ways to approach this problem. The answers would just turn into a straw-poll for which one people liked. The best thing is to do some research on the topic yourself, find two or three, _analyze_ them, determine if they work for you or not, and _try them out_. Come to us when you have a specific question about something you have attempted to do.

Comment: All that has been posted is a vague description. However, we need you to [ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We can't be sure what you want from us. Please [edit] your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know [what is on-topic here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), asking us to write the program for you and suggestions are off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

Use $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] to detect domain name and generate your dynamic content according to that.

You also have to point your all domain names DNS to your main host. You can use A records or CNAME records to do that. Recently I have done something like that and it was fairly easy.